# mysql - sql select to start from id

Tags: php, mysql

How can I start a SQL query from a specific ID...

```
id | name  |
------------
1  | Joe   |

2  | Craig |

3  | Shawn |

4  | Ryan  |

5  | Seth  |
```

I want to start from ID 3

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id >= 3";
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You wright, use `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id >= 3"`

Comment: what is the issue with this query?

Comment: please mention the problem?

Comment: use ORDER BY for right order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use also `ORDER BY` for right order

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id >= 3 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by like this

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id>=3 ORDERT BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to fetch the record where id starts with 3?? mean record where id is 3, 30, 31,32 ,33 ... 300, 301 ,302?? like this?? then try the below query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where ID LIKE '3%' ORDER BY ID ASC
```

or if you want to get the record where id is 3 or greater then 3 mean 3,4,5,6,....
then try the below query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where ID >= 3 ORDER BY ID ASC
```